# BroadcastReceiver Battery Change and FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON flag ?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my Main Activity  i'm setting this flag onCreate :

> this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

But i want on to be able to turn it off on BroadcastReceiver

> android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW"

How can i do this ?  how will my main application know that the broadcast has been received and that it should turn off this flag ? .

Answer (score 0):

You can register a `BroadcastReceiver` programmatically in your activity by calling [registerReceiver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)) in `onResume()` and [unregisterReceiver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver)) in `onPause()`:

```
// Placed at your activity level
BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent);
    if (Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW.equals(intent.getAction()) {
      // Remove the flag
    } else {
      // Battery is okay, add the flag
    }
}

public void onResume() {
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW);
  // Probably also want to receive notification that the battery has gone back up
  filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY);    
  registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
}

public void onPause() {
  unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
}
```